# How to command curl to download into stderr

Tags: bash, curl, download

I want curl command to download a file of a certain size into `stdout` and redirect output to `stderr` currently my command doesn't download the total size of my file for some reason.

```
curl -s -w "%{stderr}%{size_download}:%{speed_download}\n" http://..someurl../1000mb 2>&1
```

output of this is

`2602:118272,000`

While the size of the file is 1000mbits it's only downloading `2602` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need follow redirects? Check with verbose `-v` To follow use `-L`:

```
curl -L -s -w "%{stderr}%{size_download}:%{speed_download}\n" http://..someurl../1000mb 2>&1
```